# How to add new user to docker image when running distributed airflow architecture using docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, airflow

(THE ORIGINAL QUESTION WAS EDITED TO MAKE IT MORE CLEAR)

1. SOLUTION AT THE END OF THE QUESTION
2. ANOTHER SOLUTION IN THE ANSWER

The goal and the setup

The main goal is to run container based processing(using the DockerOperator) when the airflow celery worker is also running inside a docker container. At the moment, I'm testing the setup at one machine, but in the end I'll run the celery worker containers at separate machines operating in the same network sharing some of the airflow specific mount points(dags,logs,plugins) and user ids etc.

I'm launching the whole setup from a docker-compose.yml where I set AIRFLOW_UID to match my UID at the host machine and AIRFLOW_GID to 0 as suggested in the airflow documentation. At the host, my UID belongs to docker group, but it doesn't belong to group 0. The `/var/run/docker.sock` is mounted into the containers.

TEST 1

I followed the example represented here https://towardsdatascience.com/using-apache-airflow-dockeroperator-with-docker-compose-57d0217c8219 .
Using the above-mentioned setup with the official airflow image 2.1.4 and DockerOperator. Task run fails, which is related to the fact that the default user doesn't have the needed permissions to `/var/run/docker.sock`. (I still need to check if adding the user to group 0 at the host would solve the issue as pointed out by @JarekPotiuk in the his comment. The problem is that group 0 is the root group and most likely I'll not get permission to add the user to it)

```
[2021-09-27 05:38:30,863] {taskinstance.py:1463} ERROR - Task failed with exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 706, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked,
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 394, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1291, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1337, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1286, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1046, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 984, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/docker/transport/unixconn.py", line 30, in connect
    sock.connect(self.unix_socket)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

TEST 2

I created custom image from the official image by adding 'newuser' with an UID that matches my UID at the host and 'docker' group that matches the one at the host.

However, when I launch the setup, the user I created in the image build phase is not there and I can't understand why. There is a 'default' user with uid=1234 and gid=0. This default user is created if I use the official Image and just define AIRFLOW_UID in the docker-compose.yml.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM apache/airflow:2.1.0

USER root
RUN useradd newuser -u 1234 -g 0

RUN groupadd --gid 986 docker \
    && usermod -aG docker newuser
USER newuser
```

Also, if I don't create the newuser and just add airflow user to docker group then the airflow user is really added to the docker group as it should.

Does docker-compose overwrite the users created at the image build phase? What would be the best way to solve this issue?

SOLUTION

This solution makes it possible to user DockerOperator from airflow container to launch DockerContainers at host.

You can choose either the default UID=50000 and GID=0 or a custom UID and GID=0. Create a docker group at the host and add the chosen UID to it. Then add the airflow user inside the container into the docker group. You can do this by adding the group in the compose file

```
group_add:
  - <docker GID>
```

In addition, you have to mount the docker.sock file to the container

```
volumes:
  - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

and add a variable AIRFLOW__CORE__ENABLE_XCOM_PICKLING=True

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. I read your discussion with Jarek Potiuk and I'm applying your solution but it is not working for me. In the host my /var/run/docker.sock is owned by root:docker. I created a user in the HOST called airflow with UID (50000) and added to "docker" group (999) in the HOST. Inside the containers I'm using a user with the same UID (50000), but this user IS NOT member of other groups apart from root(0) inside the container and thus, the permission problem persists. I suspect it is necessary to create group 999 inside container and make 50000 user member to 999. Am I right?

Comment: Finally I gave up and used jccampanero solution with docker-proxy image. Despite having create my own custom airflow image setting docker group inside the container and assigning  to airflow user as secondary group, the permissions were not refreshing. I've spent too much time on this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm launching the whole setup from a docker-compose.yml where I set AIRFLOW_UID=1234 and AIRFLOW_GID=0. I'm using a docker image based on the official airflow image with the addition that I have created 'newuser' with gid=1234 and 'docker' group with gid that matches the one at the host.

You should not do it at all. The user will be created automatically by Airflow's image entrypoint when you use a differnt UID than default - see https://airflow.apache.org/docs/docker-stack/entrypoint.html#allowing-arbitrary-user-to-run-the-container. In fact all that you want to do should be possible without having to extend the Airflow image.

What you need to do, you need to create this user that you want to run inside the container ON THE HOST - not in the container. And it should belong to the `docker group` ON THE HOST - not in the container.

Docker works in the way that it uses the same kernel/users that are defined in the system, so when you run something as a user in the container, it is run with the "host" user priviledges, so you you map your docker socket to within the container, it will be able to use the socket/run docker command becaue it will have the right permissions on the host.

Therefore (in case you run your docker-compose as regular user who already belongs to docker group) the best way is the one suggested in the quick-start - i.e. run airflow with your "host" user that you are logged in with: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html

This also makes all the files created in container belong to the "logged in user" (if they are created in directories mounted inside - such as logs directory).

But if your goal is to use it in "unattended" environment, then likely creating the new user on your host and adding the user to both `0` and `docker` groups should solve the problem.

Comment: Great answer, Jarek.

Comment: Thanks for the fast and comprehensive answer! Earlier, I ran the setup using the original image. I set the AIRFLOW_UID to be the same as my user at the host. This user  belongs to docker group, but not on the 0 group. With this setup I wasn't able to launch processes using DockerOperator. I don't have permission to add this user to group 0, but I try to get it done on monday.

Comment: In my case it's not possible to add the host user to group 0 (root group) due to security reasons. At the host side, I created airflow user with UID=50000 GID=50000 and added it to docker group. When I launch the docker compose setup, the launch fails and I'm advised to use GID=0 with the default UID=50000. When I do this I'm back to square one, where I don't have permission to launch the processes from container using DockerOperator. Is it so, that if the user doesn't have root access it can't use DockerOperator from docker container?

Comment: I accepted this as an answer, although I couldn't get DockerOperator work without root privileges.

Comment: What happens if you add your UID 50000 on host to docker group and run the image with GID=0 (without adding the host user to group 0) ?

Comment: And second question - why group "0" root is a security problem ? It does not usually give any extra permissions so it should be no problem from security point of view? But maybe you have a different setup?

Comment: Host: uid=50000(airflow) gid=50000(airflow) groups=50000(airflow),985(docker)
Container:uid=50000(airflow) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
Socket permissions: srw-rw-r--. 1 root docker 0 Aug 24 11:55 /var/run/docker.sock

As in the case of custom user, I still get the permission error when trying to connect to the socket using DockerOperator.

Comment: I think the restricted group zero policy is just made up house rule. I'll ask, if I can get some sort of special permission. With the current privileges, I could just mount anything to the container and change the permissions at host by logging into container as root :D

Comment: Now I found a solution that is super simple and does not require any additional privileges. At host, create docker group and add the 'airflow run user' to this group. In docker-compose.yml set AIRFLOW_UID=<airflow run uid> and  AIRFLOW_GID=0. In the common variables add group_add: -<docker GID> . In addition, remember to mount /var/run/docker.sock to the container. With this setup, I can use DockerOperator from the celery container. I also set, AIRFLOW__CORE__ENABLE_XCOM_PICKLING=True

Answer (score 2):

As a complement to the great answer from @JarekPotiuk, if as indicated in your comments the problem is related to permissions issues when using the `DockerOperator`, you can try the following approach.

The idea is including in the `airflow` `docker-compose.yml` file a service based on the `bobrik/socat` image. Something like:

```yaml
docker-proxy:
  image: bobrik/socat
  command: "TCP4-LISTEN:2375,fork,reuseaddr UNIX-CONNECT:/var/run/docker.sock"
  ports:
    - 2375:2375
  volumes:
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
  restart: always
```

This will effectively create a *bridge* with you host `docker` daemon and would allow you to run your containers using the `DockerOperator` without permissions issues by providing an appropriate value for the `docker_url` argument:

```py
docker_based_task = DockerOperator(
    task_id="a_docker_based_one",
    docker_url="tcp://docker-proxy:2375"
    # ...
)
```

Comment: This is the quickest solution. Don't waste hours fighting against permissions, mandatory GID=0 in airflow, and secondary groups that must be refreshed . Just apply this and enjoy the life

Comment: Setting the docker group for AIRFLOW_UID at docker-compose file was maybe even simpler solution and doesn't require an extra service. That being said, It's good to have parallel solutions.